# How do I analyze vague Google Analytics data re traffic from Facebook?

Tags: google, facebook, analytics, facebook-application

We have one Facebook fan page and two personal profiles that could be sending traffic and then there are the many facebook pages of friends etc.  I am also running an ad campaign from my FB account for my husband's business which has a link from his personal FB profile and his fan page.

On Google analytics for his business we get the following referring sites from Facebook:

/ajax/emu/end.php   which is listed under    facebook.com / referral

/l.php (which is a not-found page at FB

/ajax/emu/end.php   which is listed under   apps.facebook.com

Both of the working links send me to the home page of my profile, which is the account I am working from to create and review the FB ad campaign that we are running.

Is this info telling me any useful information at all?  Is there a best practice for tracking and analyzing Facebook traffic that is a lot more granular?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `/l.php` URI is Facebook's exit/redirect page (Google strips the query string Facebook uses to redirect from links in messages, statuses, comments, etc) and the `/ajax/emu/end.php` referrer is your Facebook advertisement clicks.

The best practice for tracking link sources (particularly for advertising) is the use of Google Analytics' [campaign tracking](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55540) to embed campaign information in all URL's which you post or advertise.

The [campaign link tagging suggestions](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55518&hl=en) should help you determine how you want to organize your campaigns and you could ostensibly create a new campaign name for every link you post.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Google doesn't strip the info - that's why Facebook use the redirect functionality, thus less data is obtained. Unless of course, you use UTM tagging as suggested above, but it's not going to help on organic uplift.